# Как задать общее свойство css?

Tags: css

пользуюсь `sizing: border-box;`, но обязательно ли его вписывать для каждого класса отдельно? Можно ли прописать общее свойство, которое будет применяться ко всем классам/id и тд?

Comment: `* { box-sizing: ... }`, так конечно лучше не делать, можете отдельно для группы `div` или еще чего-то там, что у вас есть

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```